# Why into an infinite loop?

Tags: c++

I have created a program where the user enters a password according to some specifications. The whole program is already made and is done, but what ***I cannot figure out is why the program goes into an infinite loop when the password meets the requirements.*** It'll go on forever saying "enter password" and "password is valid". **I've tried changing the loop in the main function and also tried changing the loop in isValid function, have tried putting break as well but have come up empty handed.** Any clues/hints as to why this could be happening? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void displayRequirements();
void displayResult (char[]);
bool hasUpper (char []);
bool hasLower (char []);
bool hasDigit (char []);
bool hasLength(char []);
bool isValid (char []);

int main ()

{
    displayRequirements();
    
    const int size = 7;
    char password [size];
    int length;
    
    length = strlen(password);
    
    while (length < size)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter a password: ";
        cin.getline(password, size);
        length = strlen(password);
        
        isValid (password);
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    
    return 0;
}

void displayRequirements()
{
    cout << "Password Requirements: " << endl;
    cout << "   - The password should be at least 6 characters long." << endl;
    cout << "   - The password should contain at least one uppercase." << endl;
    cout << "   and at least one lowercase letter." << endl;
    cout << "   - The password should have at least one digit." << endl;
}

bool hasUpper (char input[])
{
    for (int count = 0; count < strlen(input); count++)
    {
        if (isupper(input[count]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool hasLower (char input[])
{
    for (int count = 0; count < strlen(input); count++)
    {
        if (islower(input[count]))
        {
            return true;
        }   
    }
    return false;
}


bool hasDigit (char input[])
{   
    for (int count = 0; count < strlen(input); count++)
    {
        if (isdigit(input[count]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool hasLength(char input[])
{   
    int size = 6;
    int length = strlen(input);
    
    if (size == length)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void displayResult(char input[])
{
    if (!hasLength(input))
    {
        cout << "It should be at least 6 characters long." << endl;
    }
    
    if (!hasDigit(input))
    {
        cout << "It should have at least one digit." << endl;
    }
    
    if (!hasLower(input))
    {
        cout << "It should contain at least one lowercase letter." << endl;
    }
    
    if (!hasUpper(input))
    {
        cout << "It should contain at least one uppercase letter." << endl;
    }
}

bool isValid (char input[])
{
    int length = strlen(input);

    for (int count = 0; count < 1; count++)
    {
        if (input[length] != hasUpper(input) || hasLower(input) || hasDigit(input) || hasLength(input))
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "The password is invalid." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            displayResult(input);
        }
        
        else if (input[length] == hasUpper(input) || hasLower(input) || hasDigit(input) || hasLength(input))
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Password is valid" << endl;\
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `length = strlen(password); while (length < size)` -- What did you expect `length` would be equal to?  You have not yet entered a password.  Calling `strlen` on an uninitialized `char` array invokes undefined behavior, as the null character could be anywhere.

Comment: This description of [basic_istream::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) suggests that `strlen(password)` will _always_ be less than `size` after `cin.getline(password, size)` because of how the different functions handle the nul terminator.

Comment: If you create a [mre] (MRE), you might see the problem for yourself. It would at least make debugging easier for the people volunteering to help you. First step towards a MRE: accept all passwords (since acceptance is when the infinite loop occurs).

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the `for` loop in `isValid`. It executes exactly once and doesn't actually use the `count` variable. I also don't understand the `if/else if` conditions. What is `input[length] != hasUpper(input)` supposed to be checking? I think at least some of those `||`s should be `&&`s but I don't know what exactly a valid password is supposed to mean to you. But then no matter what happens `isValid` returns `false`, _and then_ you never use the return value of `isValid` anyway...

Comment: As your code is written, it cannot works with password longer that 6 characters as your buffer size is 7 (6 + final null character).

Comment: Instead of writing all functions at once, start with one requirement (like minimal length) and debug the code until it works, then code and test next requirement until it works and so on. **As writen, your code has many problems and more complex and longer that it need to be.** Obviously, we do not do homework as otherwise, you won't learn by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I've modified your solution so it will prompt user to enter a password until a valid input is provided. The `isValid` function returns either `true` or `false`, when it's `true` it just breaks the while loop.

By the way, The requirements are checked inside the `isValid` function, using a single for loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void displayRequirements();
void displayResult (char[]);
bool hasUpper (char[]);
bool hasLower (char[]);
bool hasDigit (char[]);
bool hasLength(char[]);
bool isValid (char[]);

int main ()
{
    displayRequirements();
    const int size = 7;
    char password [size];

    // Repeat until valid password is provided
    while (true)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter a password: ";
        cin >> password;

        if(isValid(password))
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

void displayRequirements()
{
    cout << "Password Requirements: " << endl;
    cout << "   - The password should be at least 6 characters long." << endl;
    cout << "   - The password should contain at least one uppercase." << endl;
    cout << "   and at least one lowercase letter." << endl;
    cout << "   - The password should have at least one digit." << endl;
}

void displayResult(bool hasUpper, bool hasLower, bool hasDigit, bool hasLength)
{
    if (!hasLength)
        cout << "It should be at least 6 characters long." << endl;

    if (!hasDigit)
        cout << "It should have at least one digit." << endl;

    if (!hasLower)
        cout << "It should contain at least one lowercase letter." << endl;

    if (!hasUpper)
        cout << "It should contain at least one uppercase letter." << endl;
}

bool isValid (char input[])
{
    int length = strlen(input);

    // flags
    bool hasUpper = false;
    bool hasDigit = false;
    bool hasLength = length >= 6;
    bool hasLower = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if (isdigit(input[i]))
            hasDigit = true;

        if (islower(input[i]))
            hasLower = true;

        if (isupper(input[i]))
            hasUpper = true;
    }

    // If all of the requirements are met
    if (hasUpper && hasDigit && hasLength && hasLower)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "The password is valid." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        return true;
    }

    // If we got so far, it does not met one or more requirements
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Password is invalid" << endl;
    displayResult(hasUpper, hasLower, hasDigit, hasLength);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Very inefficient code as it would compute the length about 20 times for a password of length 6.

Comment: Yea, I mentioned that, but it's out of the scope of this question, lemme refactor it

Comment: It does it only twice per attempt, seems nice to me,